# 3D Rigging: Belt twist or Frame Interpolation beyond 180 degrees. Euler, Matrix, Quaternions?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, quaternions, bezier, basis

3D TD here, defining a **"Bezier curve"** and orientation along it with Control Objects' transforms. 
I'm having issues to interpolate the **"Up Vector"** between the `Control Objects`, in a way that would allow me to have a differential of more than 180 degrees between control, so I'm limited in how much I can twist.

I'm using SideFX Houdini, which has a C-like language called `VEX` for achieve them. Here you can see the control items, the Bezier handles(cyan, yellow) and the transform panel for one of them.

[image: Image of Objects and Bezier]

To generate the frames the Bezier is re-sampled to a polyline and starting at each `Control Object` corresponding point there's a **Parallel Frame Transport** up to the `Control Object` corresponding point.

This will cause breaks in the the continuity of the frames, so what I do is a weighted rotation about the tangent axis so the frames' **"Up Vector"** gradually align with the next `Control Object`'s **"Up Vector"**.

The issue is this alignment is done by checking the angle between two vectors **Frame Transport Up** and next `Control Object Up` in the same plane. Which biggest different is 180 degrees. Beyond that it flips to the other side: [Clip with Flipping Frames](https://streamable.com/u322h)

Now, I can have more than 180 if apply such twist or roll, as an offset of the **Frame Transport** and subsequent alignment, but this is an extra step. 
[Twist above 180 as Offset](https://streamable.com/l7rb3)

I understand that when dealing with matrices there's no notion of turns and so this may be impossible with what I extract from objects being posed with **Euler**. But I have a feeling there might a solution around involving quaternions, I usually use them as **Axis-Angle**, not that I fully grasp them conceptually.

My issue seems to be how I relate one control object with the next one in a way I can grasp how much twisting it takes to go from one to the other.

Looking for references that I should study to sort this. If it's even possible...

Thanks

Comment: Run a rotation minimizing frame pass (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Computation-of-rotation-minimizing-frames.pdf) so that you have a reliable "up" vector? (or run the poor man's version that forgoes the double reflection if you need more performance)

Comment: "Swing twist decomposition" around tangent vector, can help with parallel transport and separate twist control.